# Calculating the time complexity of the following code

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

Could someone please help with finding the complexity of the following code?

```
def mystery(n):
    sum = 0
    if n % 2 == 0:
        for i in range(len(n + 10000)): 
            sum += 1

    elif n % 3 == 0:
        i, j = 0, 0
        while i <= n:
            while j <= n:
                sum += j - 1
                j += 1
            i += 1
    else:
        sum = n**3
```

Would the time complexity of the following code be O(n^2) since in the worst case, the elif statement would get executed, so the outer while loop would execute n times, while the nested while loop would be executed n times **once** only because we never reset j? Therefore, we would have O(n^2 + n) and because the leading term is n^2, the complexity would be O(n^2)?

Comment: The `elif` part is only O(n).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why

Comment: because once `j == n`, it won't go to 0. So the double while is really only a single while loop of `sum += j - 1`

Comment: So would the complexity of that nested while loop be O(1) as n gets bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `elif` section:

- when `i`=0, the `while j <= n:` loop is O(n).
- when `i`>0, `j`=n+1, so the `while j <= n:` loop is O(1).

So the `elif` section is O(n) + O(n*1) = O(n+n) = O(n).